# how to solve android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line and failed to instantiate one or more class

Tags: android, android-layout, logcat

I am really frustrated by this problem I have tried all the ways to solve this kind of problem but can't fix it.

I am using this [Ramdom circle menu](https://github.com/Ramotion/circle-menu-android) library

please help me in this

> Logcat error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.codecrafted.udit.circlemenu/com.codecrafted.udit.circlemenu.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.ramotion.circlemenu.CircleMenuView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6365)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.ramotion.circlemenu.CircleMenuView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.ramotion.circlemenu.CircleMenuView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:812)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.codecrafted.udit.circlemenu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6852)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6365)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:201)
        at android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl.getValue(MiuiResourcesImpl.java:94)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1304)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.createDrawableIfNeeded(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:235)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:86)
        at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setImageResource(FloatingActionButton.java:478)
        at com.ramotion.circlemenu.CircleMenuView.initButtons(CircleMenuView.java:365)
        at com.ramotion.circlemenu.CircleMenuView.<init>(CircleMenuView.java:243)
        at com.ramotion.circlemenu.CircleMenuView.<init>(CircleMenuView.java:189)
```

> My java code

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        final CircleMenuView menu = findViewById(R.id.circle_menu);
        menu.setEventListener(new CircleMenuView.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuOpenAnimationStart(@NonNull CircleMenuView view) {
                Log.d("D", "onMenuOpenAnimationStart");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMenuOpenAnimationEnd(@NonNull CircleMenuView view) {
                Log.d("D", "onMenuOpenAnimationEnd");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMenuCloseAnimationStart(@NonNull CircleMenuView view) {
                Log.d("D", "onMenuCloseAnimationStart");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMenuCloseAnimationEnd(@NonNull CircleMenuView view) {
                Log.d("D", "onMenuCloseAnimationEnd");
            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonClickAnimationStart(@NonNull CircleMenuView view, int index) {
                Log.d("D", "onButtonClickAnimationStart| index: " + index);
            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonClickAnimationEnd(@NonNull CircleMenuView view, int index) {
                Log.d("D", "onButtonClickAnimationEnd| index: " + index);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onButtonLongClick(@NonNull CircleMenuView view, int index) {
                Log.d("D", "onButtonLongClick| index: " + index);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonLongClickAnimationStart(@NonNull CircleMenuView view, int index) {
                Log.d("D", "onButtonLongClickAnimationStart| index: " + index);
            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonLongClickAnimationEnd(@NonNull CircleMenuView view, int index) {
                Log.d("D", "onButtonLongClickAnimationEnd| index: " + index);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> Xml message

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.ramotion.circlemenu.CircleMenuView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException   at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.obtainTypedArray(Resources_Delegate.java:531)   at android.content.res.Resources.obtainTypedArray(Resources.java:615)   at com.ramotion.circlemenu.CircleMenuView.<init>(CircleMenuView.java:208)   at com.ramotion.circlemenu.CircleMenuView.<init>(CircleMenuView.java:189)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394) Copy stack to clipboard
```

i dont know how to use View.isInEditMode() please show me how to do it. This may solve the problem

> Xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    app:button_colors="@array/colors"
    app:button_icons="@array/icons"
    android:background="#000"
    >
    <com.ramotion.circlemenu.CircleMenuView
        android:id="@+id/circle_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:button_colors="@array/colors"
        app:button_icons="@array/icons"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What's in your `colors` and `icons` arrays?

Comment: Try Rebuild/Clean Project, if it doesn't work, then also try Invalidate Cache / Restart

Comment: if invalidating the cache didn't worked out, then try to change the app theme to something else like Material.Light.DarkActionBar

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
app:button_colors="@array/colors"
    app:button_icons="@array/icons"
```

from `RelativeLayout`